# Insert array into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am super confused and have been searching. But as the title suggests I am trying to enter an array.
My question is how do I get this array to import into the database? As of now with the current script, it only imports the first record and not the rest. Here also, I am able to import other values within the same array this is a JSON call by the way and its already being decoded.

```
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($output[$key]["stats"]["damage_given"]["vehicle"])) {
        $damage_given[$key] = $output[$key]["stats"]["damage_given"]["vehicle"];
            foreach ($damage_given[$key] as $vehicle_name) {
                $vehicle_dmg_id         = $vehicle_name['id'];
                $vehicle_dmg_name       = $vehicle_name['name'];
                $vehicle_dmg_value      = $vehicle_name['value'];
                $vehicle_dmg_faction_nc = $vehicle_name['faction']['nc'];
                $vehicle_dmg_faction_tr = $vehicle_name['faction']['tr'];
                $vehicle_dmg_faction_vs = $vehicle_name['faction']['vs'];
            }
     }
}

$add_dmg_veh = "INSERT INTO damage_given(character_number, vehicle_id,
vehicle_name, total_value, vehicle_faction_nc, vehicle_faction_tr,
vehicle_faction_vs) VALUES ('$character_id[$key]', '$vehicle_dmg_id', 
'$vehicle_dmg_name','$vehicle_dmg_value', '$vehicle_dmg_faction_nc', 
'$vehicle_dmg_faction_tr','$vehicle_dmg_faction_vs')";
```

Comment: I think you need to insert the insert query within the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not recommended to store an array in a database, you could `serialize()` your array to store it in a database. Basically, PHP will convert the array into a specially crafted string, which it can later interpret.

[Serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to store it in the database, and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it to work with it when you pull it out of the database

**Note:** I say serialization is not recommended, because your database is then not in [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), specifically because you are storing non-atomic values inside of a particular entry in the database. For this case, I would recommend creating a separate table which can store these values individually, and link the two tables together with a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking about PDO_MySQL and your insert string is outside the loop and should be execute inside it.

Comment: I was looking at redoing my code using PDO instead of mysqli would I be able to insert an associative array with it ?

Comment: No, that will have to be you. Using PDO_MySQL is for safety reasons.
You can have a prepared statement and then just push the values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the array and insert every field of the array by it's own.

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    // execute your insert statement here with $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't insert array in MySQL as you are doing .. Do as with iterating..

```
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($output[$key]["stats"]["damage_given"]["vehicle"])) {
        $damage_given[$key] = $output[$key]["stats"]["damage_given"]["vehicle"];
            foreach ($damage_given[$key] as $vehicle_name) {
                $vehicle_dmg_id         = $vehicle_name['id'];
                $vehicle_dmg_name       = $vehicle_name['name'];
                $vehicle_dmg_value      = $vehicle_name['value'];
                $vehicle_dmg_faction_nc = $vehicle_name['faction']['nc'];
                $vehicle_dmg_faction_tr = $vehicle_name['faction']['tr'];
                $vehicle_dmg_faction_vs = $vehicle_name['faction']['vs'];


                // if you wants to use insert query then do here.
                $add_dmg_veh = "INSERT INTO damage_given(character_number, vehicle_id, 
                vehicle_name, total_value, vehicle_faction_nc, vehicle_faction_tr, 
                vehicle_faction_vs) VALUES ('$character_id[$key]', '$vehicle_dmg_id',
                '$vehicle_dmg_name', '$vehicle_dmg_value', '$vehicle_dmg_faction_nc',
                '$vehicle_dmg_faction_tr', '$vehicle_dmg_faction_vs')";

            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try building your insert data in an array and then implode the results into a single query:

```
<?php
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($output[$key]["stats"]["damage_given"]["vehicle"])) {
        $damage_given[$key] = $output[$key]["stats"]["damage_given"]["vehicle"];
            foreach ($damage_given[$key] as $vehicle_name) {

                $sql[] = "
                    (
                    ".$vehicle_name['id'].",
                    ".$vehicle_name['name'].",
                    ".$vehicle_name['value'].",
                    ".$vehicle_name['faction']['nc'].",
                    ".$vehicle_name['faction']['tr'].",
                    ".$vehicle_name['faction']['vs']."
                    )";
            }
    }
}

$query = "
INSERT INTO damage_given
(
character_number,
vehicle_id, 
vehicle_name, 
total_value, 
vehicle_faction_nc, 
vehicle_faction_tr, 
vehicle_faction_vs
) 
VALUES
".implode(",",$sql)."
";
?>
```

Comment: I got it to work without using implode or explode Code below! and thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

here is what I got to fix the problem!

$stmt = $dbh->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO kills_vehicle (character_number, veh_id, veh_name, veh_total, veh_faction_nc, veh_faction_tr, veh_faction_vs)
            VALUES(:char_id, :id, :vehname, :total_value, :faction_nc, :faction_tr, :faction_vs)");

```
    foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($output[$key]["stats"]["play_time"]["vehicle"])) {
            $character_id[$key]    = $output[$key]["id"];
            $score_hit_count[$key] = $output[$key]["stats"]["kills"]["vehicle"];
            foreach ($score_hit_count[$key] as $row) {

                $stmt->bindValue(':char_id', $character_id[$key]);
                $stmt->bindValue(':id', $row[id]);
                $stmt->bindValue(':vehname', $row[name]);
                $stmt->bindValue(':total_value', $row[value]);
                $stmt->bindValue(':faction_nc', $row[faction][nc]);
                $stmt->bindValue(':faction_tr', $row[faction][tr]);
                $stmt->bindValue(':faction_vs', $row[faction][vs]);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }
```